# How uniform is the distribution of elements in the universe?

Tags: astrochemistry

I was wondering about element distribution in the universe, specifically if any inconsistency in the relative distribution of elements would have any significant effects on the chemistry of a galaxy. How likely is it that there could be significant differences in element quantities from one galaxy to another, so that certain common, or 'important' chemical compounds or reactions might not be possible/probable.

For example could a galaxy not have the proper relative quantities of elements used in organic chemistry to allow the sort of organic chemistry we see occurring in many places in our own local space (comets and cosmic dust)?

Comment: Related: [Is the relative natural abundance of isotopes of an element the same everywhere?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33056/is-the-relative-natural-abundance-of-isotopes-of-an-element-the-same-everywhere/33070#33070)

Comment: Take a look at : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlBG_A4Djp4
It explains the s-process

Comment: @QuantumAMERICCINO I really enjoyed that, and while I don't have the expertise to answer my own question, it makes it clear to me that any variation in elements probably lies entirely with the composition of star types in a given space.  Perhaps the question is better suited for a astronomy focused exchange?