# Do most elements generally exist in a planet during early formation, or is it a small subset?

Tags: geochemistry

I'm interested in whether there are a small subset of elements that are by far the most common in a planet's early stages of formation and a wider range are formed slowly over time through chemical reaction, or if a very wide range of the periodic table can be initially found from the start.

Obviously every planet it unique, but I'm asking about whether there's a common scenario / elemental ratio present in the hot cataclysmic early stages of a planet's formation, or rather it's pretty much diverse from the start. Do most elements generally exist in a planet during early formation, or is it a small subset?

Comment: If you mean "stars", [this earlier answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33056/is-the-relative-natural-abundance-of-isotopes-of-an-element-the-same-everywhere/33070#33070) may have some useful info and links.

Comment: Assuming the planet wasn't created in the Universe's early infancy (say a few hundred million years after the Big Bang), it's more likely that there are *less* elements on a planet as time goes by. See [extinct radionuclides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinct_radionuclide). That is, unless your planet goes on to [develop an advanced technological civilisation...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_element)

Comment: The only process that can create elements on a planet is radioactive decay, but that removes more elements than it creates (and mostly add to the stock of elements already present). But, the mix of elements on the *surface* of a planet is heavily influenced by geophysical processes which concentrate some in the surface and others in the core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements are not formed through chemical reactions or in planets (except through nuclear decay) . They are formed in stars through nuclear reactions.

Your heavier elements can't even be formed in your typical star. It takes a supernova.

So pretty much everything the planet is made of is there from the start.

Comment: Exception is helium, which is from alfa decay ( as helium of big bang origin escaped ) and beryllium + boron from [cosmic ray spalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray_spallation) of
 nuclei.

Comment: Nice answer, also add lead (Pb) which is constantly forming among other radioactive decay products like radon gas.